# Change article edition workflow

Tags: articles, com-content, article-manager, workflow

I have to make some changes on the article edition workflow to add some features in the middle of the current edition process.

I mean, the articles when published must be saved in a different status, and will be approved by the admin before being published. Also if an author edits the article, I must keep the original article published and the new version will be in pending status until it is approved and the original article is updated. I was thinking of duplicating the article programmatically to suit this task.

I was wondering, what do I have to override, if I have to change the article edition component (is it `com_content`?), or what do you suggest that I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will need a custom component and a plugin:

- the plugin will change the state of new articles to unpublished. `onContentBeforeSave` event will help you with that. More details about the content events can be found [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content).
- the component will list new versions of articles. You will need some kind of task there to accept a new version and update the original article.

Another way you can try instead of plugin is to set up the permissions and disable "Edit State".

Comment: First thing I have to do is override the `com_content` admin component, in a way that when I open the article for edition, I'll be able to load its content in memory. Any idead of how do I do that?

Comment: You cannot override it that way. You can override only layouts, but you will need more logic. So I advice you to write your own simple component to manage articles that way.

Comment: Look at this question I've made, and the solution. Is it the best way? http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/cant-override-com-content-controller

Comment: Honestly I am not a fun of overriding. As a developer I am preferring to code custom solutions.

Comment: Ok then.. how do I do in a plugin, that, when the user opens the article for edition (without even changing something), I can get the content of the article and save it in memory. Which event should I use?

Comment: Just a note - I am talking about the site part, because in the administrator `com_content` does not fire any events. When a user opens the article for edition it would be `onContentPrepare`.