# Can't override com_content controller

Tags: articles, overrides, com-content

I'm trying to override com_content controller (`administrator/components/com_content/controller.php`), for this I have installed the [joomla-override](https://github.com/juliopontes/joomla-override) plugin and followed as the documentation says.

Created a `code` folder inside the root of `administrator/` directory, and inside of it I've created a `com_content` directory with a file named `controller.php` in its root.

The file look like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_content
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Component Controller
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_content
 * @since       1.5
 */
class ContentController extends ContentControllerDefault
{

        /**
         * @var         string  The default view.
         * @since   1.6
         */
        protected $default_view = 'articles';

        /**
         * Method to display a view.
         *
         * @param   boolean                     If true, the view output will be cached
         * @param   array  An array of safe url parameters and their variable types, for valid values see {@link JFilterInput::clean()}.
         *
         * @return  JController         This object to support chaining.
         *
         * @since   1.5
         */
        public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
        {
             var_dump("Test");
             return $this;
        }

}
```

As you can see, the class name follows the overriding rules of the plugin extending the `ContentControllerDefault.

The `var_dump` should appear below the article edition form, but it is not shown. It's like the class is not being overriden. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. Solved it. The problem was I was putting the `code/` folder in `administrator/` root, instead I should have put it inside the template folder (`administrator/templates/my_template/code/`).

Now it works.

Comment: Don't forget to select your solution as the answer :)